# EventMachine on Heroku with Rails & EM-C2DM Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, eventmachine, thin, reactor

Trying to use the GroupMe gem EM-C2DM, https://github.com/groupme/em-c2dm, a Google C2DM Ruby Library using Event Machine, within Rails. I know it should work on Heroku as there is a configuration specific to Heroku, however I can't seem to get it to run.

I'm executing via a Resque Worker, and the worker works correctly and gets queued and called.  However it fails to ever get past authenticating and never reports on the response of the push notification.  It seems to just never finish.

```
  module PushAndroid

  require "eventmachine"
  require "em-c2dm"

  @queue = :android_push

  def self.perform(opts)
    puts "entering android push"
    EM.next_tick do
      EM::C2DM.authenticate(ENV["C2DM_EMAIL"], ENV["C2DM_PASSWORD"])
      @push = Push.find(opts['push_id'])
      message = "Message #{@push.title}"
      push_id = "#{@push.id}"
      opts['tokens'].each{ |token|
        EM::C2DM.push(token, :message => message, :push_id => push_id) do |response|
            if response.success?
                puts "success! id=#{response.id}" # ID of sent message
            else
                puts "response:"
                puts response.inspect
                #case response.error
                #when "InvalidToken"
                    # reauthenticate
                #when "InvalidRegistration"
                    # clear our registration id
                #when "RetryAfter"
                    # pause sending for response.retry_after seconds
                #end        
            end
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried it without using EM::next_tick or EM.next_tick and it gets past authentication, however never pushes anything, never returns a response or anything. It never enters EM::next_tick in fact.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?  This is on Heroku, using Rails 3.1.1 with Thin

From my Gemfile.lock:

```
   thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)

eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4)

    em-apn (0.0.3)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.3)
      yajl-ruby (>= 0.8.2)
    em-http-request (1.0.2)
      addressable (>= 2.2.3)
      cookiejar
      em-socksify
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
      http_parser.rb (>= 0.5.3)
    em-socksify (0.2.0)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)

  remote: git://github.com/groupme/em-c2dm.git
  revision: 2d853ff771908785f23b8c64fa5d5508b4eba40a
  specs:
    em-c2dm (0.0.1)
      em-http-request (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.3)
      uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in a EM.run has fixed the problem. I guess the Workers don't connect to Thin, therefore need to run their own Reactor